# Expected number of moves needed to turn on all the n bulbs by tossing a baised coin with p% probability?

Tags: probability

There are n bulbs. Initially, each bulb are turned off. In each move you can select one random bulb (Probability of selecting each bulb is same). If the bulb is already turned on, you do nothing. If the bulb is turned off, you must toss a coin. If it’s head, you can turn the bulb on, but if it’s tail, the bulb will remain off.

To make the problem even more boring, the coin is not a fair coin, the chance of landing a tail is p%.

What is the expected number of moves needed to turn on all the bulbs?

I want to know the algorithm or solution process for it as n is variable for this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a mathematics question, not a programming question. Did you mean to post on [math.se] ?

Comment: I had asked to know the algorithm for it. Thay's why I had posted here. Updating my problem description. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Naive approach: Monte-Carlo-Simulation

#### Description

(You did not give any information on what kind of solution you want, therefore i present the probably most simple but still powerful approach: simulation)

The Monte-Carlo method allows us to simulate this stochastic-process and observe the number of steps needed. As this is only a noisy estimation, we need to do this many times. Using an infinite number of runs, this solution will converge to the theoretical one!

#### Code

Here is some simple python-based code:

```python
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # just for plotting

n = 10
p = 0.7
n_samples = 1000000

def run():
    states = [0 for i in range(n)]
    steps = 0
    while 0 in states:
        index = random.randint(0, n-1)
        if random.random() < p:        # non-fair coin
            states[index] = 1
        steps += 1
    return steps

avg = 0.0
samples = []
for sample in range(n_samples):
    steps = run()
    avg += steps
    samples.append(steps)

print(avg / n_samples)
plt.hist(samples)
plt.show()
```

#### Code output

```
41.853233
```

[image]

### Math approach: Absorbing Markov Chain

#### Description

As the probabilities describing the state-change of light-bulbs is only dependent on the current state, the **Markov-assumption** is valid and we can use **Markov-Chains** to obtain the average steps needed.

Because the final state will self-loop forever and because it will be reached given an infinite number of steps, this is an **Absorbing Markov Chain**.

As all light bulbs are the same, we don't need to model transitions where each combination of activated light bulbs maps to each other. We can reduce it to the much simpler: 0 light-bulbs -> 1 light-bulbs -> ... (and the self-loops of course).

The discrete-time discrete-state-space Absorbing Markov Chain allows a simple and powerful calculation of the desired value.

Some theory is explained at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Fundamental_matrix). It's also the source for the formulas in use for the following code.

#### Code

Again some python:

```python
import numpy as np

N = 10
P = 0.7

""" Build transition matrix """
trans_mat = np.zeros((N+1, N+1))
for source_state in range(N):
    prob_hitting_next = ((N-source_state) / float(N)) * P
    inverse = 1.0 - prob_hitting_next
    trans_mat[source_state, source_state] = inverse
    trans_mat[source_state, source_state+1] = prob_hitting_next
trans_mat[N, N] = 1.0

""" Will look like this:
[[ 0.3   0.7   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.37  0.63  0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.44  0.56  0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.51  0.49  0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.58  0.42  0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.65  0.35  0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.72  0.28  0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.79  0.21  0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.86  0.14  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.93  0.07]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.  ]]
"""

""" Q:      the sub-matrix of trans_mat without
            the rows and columns of any absorbing states
    N_fund: fundamental matrix
    t:      expected number of steps before beeing absorved for each start-state
"""
Q_sub = trans_mat[:N, :N]
N_fund = np.linalg.inv(np.eye(N) - Q_sub)
t = np.dot(N_fund, np.ones(N))
print(t)
print(t[0])  # this is the value we want
```

#### Code output

```
[ 41.84240363  40.4138322   38.82653061  37.04081633
  35. 32.61904762 29.76190476  26.19047619  21.42857143  14.28571429]

41.8424036281   # less than 1 second calculation time!
```

Comment: I kind of feel sad for not receiving any comments on my code.

Comment: I am overwhelmed seeing your code. Though my question was for the formula that I could derive, I loved your solution and code.